# Integration of Graphexp and JanusGraph via Gremlin

Tags: janusgraph, graphexp

I generated one small graph of 3 nodes in gremlin (JanusGraph; in-memory database), I want to visualize this graph using Graphexp.

Please let me know how to integrate these two.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/bricaud/graphexp#configuration):

> Next step, configure the server settings on the bottom of the page. The default Gremlin server address is `localhost:8182`. You will have to specify the communication protocol `websocket` or `REST` and the gremlin server version. Graphexp is not able to handle secure connections yet and a contribution on this topic would be welcome.

The configuration is added to the file `graphConf.js`.